# Get "Unique" in array without filtering on sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I extract unique values from a column and put them in an array with a code like this:

```
Range("A1:A27").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("Z1"), Unique:=True
Univoci = Range("Z1").CurrentRegion.Value
```

The question is: it's possible to put them directly into the array?

I mean with one command or with minimum code (I know that I can get unique values by comparing every item with the others)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way to initalise and fill an array with unique values off the bat, but you can use a dictionary to build up the unique entries

```
  Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For Each Cell In Range("A1:A27")
    If Not Dict.Exists(Cell.Value) Then Dict.Add Cell.Value, Cell.Address
  Next

  Dim itemArray() As Variant
  ReDim itemArray(0 To Dict.Count - 1)
  For Each Value In Dict.Keys
    itemArray(i) = Value
    i = i + 1
  Next
```

You may not need to cast the dictionary into an array, as you could access the dictionary key values directly for further coding, which would cut down on the lines of code as well.

Comment: Thanks, it works, and it seems very fast but when I'll run it in a macro will be just as fast?

Answer (score 0):

This will get the unique Text items in column A and put them in Column B

```
Sub GetuniqueItems()

    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c
    Dim Col As New Collection, Ar(), x

    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rws, 1))

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each c In Rng.Cells

        Col.Add c.Value, c.Value

    Next c

    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim Ar(1 To Col.Count)

    For x = 1 To Col.Count

        Ar(x) = Col(x)

    Next x

    Range("B1").Resize(Col.Count, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Ar)

End Sub
```

Comment: I ran it but "Col" don't takes any value from the selected range (without errors displayed)